# How to add gradient color to Divider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Divider widget with a solid color but I want to set it to a gradient color. Is there a way to do this?

```
Divider(
    height: 20,
    thickness: 2.5,
    indent: 0,
    endIndent: 100,
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a `Container()` with [BoxDecoration][1] to create a gradient.

```
SizedBox(
  width: 200,
  height: 4,
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: //...
    ),
  ),
),
```

The pre-defined divider is good but not powerful when it comes to customization.
[1]: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html

Comment: Missing a comma after the 4, wouldn't let me edit it because an edit to a post must be 6 or more characters

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use the exact same parameters as the official Divider and yet have the possibility to gradient AND to round these nasty square sides, you can use this ds is my DividerStyle containing the parameters:

```
    return SizedBox(
    height: ds.heigth,
    child: Center(
      child: Container(
        height: ds.thickness,
        margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: ds.indent, end: ds.endIndent),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: ds.color.getColor(),
          gradient: ds.color.getGradient(),
          borderRadius: ds.roundEdge
              ? BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(ds.thickness))
              : null,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent, width: 1),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```